# Where is the Arch Linux official package source repository?

Tags: arch-linux

After searching Google and the wiki I can't seem to find it, but only links to the *software* repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Found a link!

- Reference [Subversion repository](https://www.archlinux.org/svn/)
- Browseable [Git clone](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/)